# How to check api response on regular interval after hitting it once

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am creating NestJs application where I am hitting to some third party api form where I am getting resposne some like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "status": "PENDING"
  }
}
```

In this resposne status has two values `ALLOWED` or `PENDING`.
Now when I am hitting api for the very first time its shows above response where status is `pending`.Now I don't  want to hit api again and again manually to check whether status is `allowed` or not.

Is there any way so that it can automatically check whether status in response is `ALLOWED` or not.

Comment: You would need a persistent connection like Websockets or Server Sent Events for that, other than your only choice is polling at some interval.

Comment: Is there any references fr server sent events

Comment: you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events, but the problem is, since this is a third party API and you're calling it from your backend code, none of these seem like an option.

Comment: What about cron job option

Comment: that's a possibility

Answer (score 0):

Given that is a third party API over which you have no control, unless they expose some sort of persistent socket connection, the short answer is **NO**.

At the moment, it seems like your only choice is to poll the API at a certain interval and check.

EDIT: If it is not required to send a response when `status` changes to `ALLOWED`, then you can perform CRON jobs as well, but the basic concept remains the same regardless, you're gonna have to hit the API at a certain interval to get updated values.